# Merging multiple images to get a video in OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, video, frames

What I want to do is to produce a video composed from a single image, repeated for many frames.

I have tried the below code but it is producing a video file of size 0 bytes.

```
IplImage *image = cvLoadImage("images/img1.jpg", 1);
CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("Video from Images.flv",
                                            CV_FOURCC('D','I','V','X'), fps, size);
for(int counter=0; counter < 300; counter++)
{
    /*The below statement writes the frame one by one to the video ...*/
    cvWriteFrame(writer, image);
}
```

Comment: opencv's old c-api died in 2010 already. please stop living under a rock.

Comment: so what all you can do about it?

Comment: try -1 for the fourcc, and look at the [c++ docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter)

Comment: actually i am working on ubuntu, so i don't think -1 will work. Actually the frames which i am having are of a .flv video, but i am not getting fourcc code for .flv

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [cvReleaseVideoWriter(CvVideoWriter** writer)](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#releasevideowriter) at the end.
Had you used the C++ API, the destructor would have taken care of this for you.

Comment: hey, i did use cvReleaseVideoWriter in my code . Its just that i didn't post those lines here in my code. I am getting a blank video which has nothing to display.

Comment: Well probably `cvCreateVideoWriter()` returns NULL then, which could mean you have a codec issue, as suggested by berak. Or maybe there was error reading image, did you try displaying it in your program  to check? The blank - does that mean it it has 0 frames, or 300 blank frames?